# Как представить функцию внутри класса с доступом к переменным(при подмене)

Tags: c++

Хочу Подменить такую вот функцию - внутри класса.

```
    void UStruct::Serialize( FArchive& Ar )
{
    Super::Serialize( Ar ); //UFiled Serialize
    Ar << ScriptText << Children;
}
```

Здесь доступ к переменным ScripText, Children и тд прямой, без переопределения. 
Проблема в том что я не пойму - как следует представить функцию перехватчик чтобы в ней был тот самый доступ напрямую и без переопределения - это возможно ?
Я пытался представить эту функцию таким образом

```
void __fastcall UStructS_hookNew(void* _this,int edx,FArchive& Ar)//, UStruct &st)
{

    hUField__Serialize(_this,edx,Ar);
    UStruct* st = (UStruct*)malloc(sizeof(UStruct));
    Ar << st->ScriptText << st->Children;
}
```

Но так программа падает с ошибкой. В самом классе есть так же несколько конструкторов

```
    UStruct( ENativeConstructor, INT InSize, const TCHAR* InName, const TCHAR* InPackageName, DWORD InFlags, UStruct* InSuperStruct );
UStruct( EStaticConstructor, INT InSize, const TCHAR* InName, const TCHAR* InPackageName, DWORD InFlags );
UStruct( UStruct* InSuperStruct );
```

Но я не очень понимаю - когда идет прямой доступ `UStruct::Serialize`,разве для него используется конструктор ?
И как тогда следует правильно представить это ?

Comment: Вы хотите в классе заменить невиртуальный метод? Ваше пожелание неясно.

Comment: @gbg я хочу изменить в программе оригинальный метод Ustruct::Serialize на мой(Методом хука/Инжекта), @Abyx - а по другому не как ? в IDA все выглядит не очень, к примеру` ScriptText` Это `v4 = sub_10101965(v2, (char *)v3 + 64); ` Нельзя ли по другому ? Тут лишь вся проблема в переопределении ! Просто я подменял уже операторы подобного рода, но там структура была в стеке, т.е Serialize(Farchive& Ar, UStruct& st) а тут получается напрямую, возможно ли как то это решить без IDA, ибо вся структура у меня есть этих функций.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такс ну в общем помогли мне на другом форуме - ничего особенного было, просто надо было `_this` указывать от `__fastcall`, при переопределении `ustruct st`, чтоб все выглядело вот так -

```
UStruct* st = (UStruct*)_this;
```